# Custom Posts Query and meta_query Sort Order

Tags: posts, post-meta

*Preface: I'm fairly new to the more complicated Wordpress development, but not new to PHP.*

I am having an issue with getting a custom posts query to order exactly as I want. I am using a plugin that gives the ability to set a **post** to **featured**. In the `postmeta` table, this goes in as `meta_key: __is_featured` with `meta_value: yes`.

When a post is no longer featured, the `meta_value` becomes `no`. If a post has not had the post featured set at all, there is no record in `postmeta` table.

I want to order the posts on the page as **featured: yes** first, followed by every other item in **date** order. I have this working, as long as post is no longer featured. Posts that are not featured anymore, still get sorted before anything else.

#### My Query

```
$category = get_query_var('category');

$args = array(
    'category_name' => $category,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value post_date',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key' => '_is_featured',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => 'yes'
        ],
        [
            'key' => '_is_featured',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ],
        [
            'key' => '_is_featured',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => 'no'
        ],
    ]
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

#### The Results

```
Post-featured: yes
Post-featured: no
Post-featured: null
Post-featured: null
Post-featured: null
Post-featured: null
```

#### What I want

```
Post-featured: yes
Post-featured: null
Post-featured: null
Post-featured: no
Post-featured: null
Post-featured: null
```

Comment: It seems like removing the post meta row when a post is no longer featured would simplify your life. It would also simplify the query, which I imagine is pretty dog slow, as post meta queries tend to be.

Comment: @milo unfortunately I don't really have control of the plugin to remove the row

Comment: Scratch that, I've edited the plugin. Just have to make sure it never gets updated.

Comment: You could also just do 2 queries first one get the featured posts and second get the rest...

Comment: @Shibi I think this is what I'm going to go with, just seems a bit of a waste.

Comment: which plugin create this meta ? Is it a free one of wordpress.org ?